# Why is this set relationship false?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working through an HW (Discrete Math p42, Goodaire et al) on set theory and do not understand why the answer is false.

$ \{ 1,2 \} \in \{1,2,\{\{ 1,2 \}\}\} $

I am interpreting this as the set $\{1,2\}$ belongs to the set on the right. I see set {1,2} within another set on the right, so why is it false? I think there is some confusion in my understanding of "belongs to" and "subset."

if the question instead asked $ \{ 1,2 \} \subsetneq
 \{1,2,\{\{ 1,2 \}\}\} $ would this be true?

Thanks!

Comment: Because $\{\{1,2\}\}$ is not the same as $\{1,2\}.$ The first is a set with one element, the second is a set with two elemental.

Comment: @JohnDouma You use "the set" to reference two different sets there. Apt to be a bit confusing, indeed, $\{1,2\}$ is an element of $\{\{1,2\}\},$ which was previous called "the set."

Comment: The expression $\{1,2\}\in\{1,2,\{\{1,2\}\}\}$ means that $\{1,2\}$ is an element of the set $\{1,2,\{\{1,2\}\}\}$. This is the same as saying that $\{\{1,2\}\}$ is an element of the set $\{1,2,\{\{1,2\}\}\}$. That is not the case, because $1$ and $2$ are elements of $\{1,2,\{\{1,2\}\}\}$, but $\{\{1,2\}\}$ is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a = 1$, $b = 2$, and $c = \{1, 2\}$.

We are tasked with determining whether $\{1, 2\} \in \{a, b, c\}$.

The set $\{a, b, c\}$, by its very definition, has the property that for all $x$, $x \in \{a, b, c\}$ if, and only if, either $x = a$, $x = b$, or $x = c$.

So we are tasked with determining whether $\{1, 2\}$ is equal to one of $a, b$, and $c$.

It can be shown that $\{1, 2\} \neq 1$, and that $\{1, 2\} \neq 2$. Depending on your assumptions about how numbers and sets relate, this may be trivial or it may be complicated. But it can be shown nonetheless.

So the question is whether $\{1, 2\} = \{\{1, 2\}\}$. The answer to this question is “no”. Suppose on the contrary that the answer were “yes”. Then $1 \in \{1, 2\} = \{\{1, 2\}\}$, and therefore $1 = \{1, 2\}$. But we’ve already shown that this is false.